# Not able to access Prolog file

Tags: c#, ffi, swi-prolog

I'm learning swi-prolog connectivity using C# and I have a problem in the following code:

```
public static void Main()
{    
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("SWI_HOME_DIR", @"C:\\Program Files\\swipl");
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", @"C:\\Program Files\\swipl");
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", @"C:\\Program Files\\swipl\\bin");

    String[] param = { "-q", "-f", @"deepak.pl" };
    try
    {
        PlEngine.Initialize(param);
        PlQuery.PlCall("assert(mother(lia,deniel))");
        PlQuery.PlCall("assert(brother(deniel,lucy))");
    }
    catch (PlException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.MessagePl);
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        PlEngine.PlCleanup();
    }
}
```

On debugging the above program it gets executed but no changes occur in the actual .pl file.

Can someone please help me out with this problem?

Comment: Why would running the PlEngine change the .pl source file?

Comment: Your environment variables are messed up; use either `@"C:\Program Files\swipl"` or `"C:\\Program Files\\swipl"`, not both.

Comment: Removed tag from title.